# System is rebooting continuously

Tags: windows-7, bios

I installed Windows 7 on an old machine and after some time, it hung. When I tried rebooting, it got stuck in reboot loop. Currently, if I switch on power, I just see Acer logo, and an option to go to bios, and then system reboots again.

There is no beeping sound, I cleaned up and plugged all hardware back again. I even tried to reset the bios settings, and that didn't help either.

I just want to figure out what part might have gone bad, if that's the case here.

Edit:

I tried using repair disk created for windows 7. Ran the tests, and it couldn't find any errors. And yet, after the disk check, system reboots as if it can't find the OS.

Edit:
I am trying a system restore from the recovery tools to see if it works.

Edit: 
It didn't work either.

Edit:
Ok, I made the BIOS to do a full check instead of quick check. It displays a lot more information now. Final screen says "Press Esc to Boot" and counts down for 8 seconds. At that point, it doesn't matter what I do, it just reboots.

Also, I forgot to mention it is AMI Bios designed for Acer.

Edit: Tried resetting the bios as well. Same problem. I hear a single faint beep on reboot. Apparently it is DRAM refresh failure. So, I have tried refitting the RAM again. But, still no luck.

Edit:

Here is a video of the issue. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orgvYTqMqZM

Comment: Do you have the make and model of the machine? In the bios is there anywhere you can disable the splash screen so you can actually see what the machine is doing prior restarting...

Comment: Let me see, if I can do that. It is a really old desktop with old school pentium 4, 2gb ram, and GMA series chipset with a SATA HDD. I was planning to use this as NAS server.

Comment: Ok, so, got the OEM logo disabled. It is detecting the HDD as slave, and then there is a split-second 2 line message (which I couldn't read) and then reboot.

Comment: Although, I don't have Windows 7 bootable disk with me anymore. I have 8.1 64 bit though. I don't think that can be used to repair the system partition.

Comment: Hmm doesn't sound too happy. can you try to catch those two lines by using the Pause | Break key to pause the screen...

Comment: Sounds like hard drive be busted... Load from a LIveCD or similar to see if it can load up at all

Comment: Ok, let me try using Pause key. I think this would be the first time I am using that key.

Comment: Apparently, it is near impossible to pause that damn thing.

Comment: Ok, after hundreds of tries, I was able to read the last two lines. It says some status = ok. It looks like SMART test is running fine. No idea what is the next thing BIOS is looking for.

Comment: Try unplugging the keyboard.

Comment: Ok, last try. Let's see what happens.

Comment: video the screen with a phone or other camcorder if you can, then you can freeze the message

Comment: That didn't work either.